# Bootstrap Blazor Popover - Can't display table

Tags: javascript, c#, html, blazor, popper.js

I'm using Bootstrap Blazor, and can't figure out how to display a html table inside a PopOver.

According to documentation on blazor.zone, it should be possible to use this in a PopOver.

I found that there are some Sanitizer javascript that can be used to allow certain html tags.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer

But i don't know how to do this from c# Blazor code.

If someone can give a code example about this, i would be thankful

```
<Popover Placement="Placement.Auto" Title="@Title" Content="@Content" IsHtml="true" Trigger="click">
    <Button Text="Show popover" />
</Popover>


@code {
    private static readonly string Title = "popup title";

    private static readonly string Content = "<table><thead><tr><th>Test</th><th>Test2</th></tr></thead></table>";
}
```

When the popover is displayed, it does not show the html table inside it